# When trying to play a video from url in a videoview, I get a FileNotFoundException: No content provider error on SOME phones

Tags: java, android

I have a video on a server that I want to play in a videoview.

On my LG G pro (4.1.2) it works like a charm, but it doesnt work on an old nexus (4.1.2) and HTC Desire X (android 4.0.4)

Here is my code:

```
videoUrl = video.getUrl();
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
vvVideoFullscreen.setVideoURI(videoUri);
```

video.getUrl() returns the following string:

```
http://sdf.mysite.com/upload/video/456456.mp4
```

Pretty straightforward. What should I do about this?

I was told that the video file has the right mp4 compression format: h.264 baseline, as outlined here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Here is the error log:

```
 D/MediaPlayer(3963): setDataSource(Context context,  http://sdf.mysite.com/upload/video/456456.mp4, Map<String, String> headers) in
 E/MediaPlayer(3963): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:  http://sdf.mysite.com/upload/video/456456.mp4
 V/MediaPlayer(3963): network type=wifi
```

Also, I tried playing the video via intent this way:

```
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, videoUri);
    intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "video/mp4");
    startActivity(intent);
```

But I got the following log messages (the video didnt play)

```
06-03 19:19:48.129: D/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(129): connect to http://sdf.mysite.com/upload/video/456456.mp4 @19601517
06-03 19:19:48.139: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-autoclose)=true
06-03 19:19:48.139: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-buffertime)=7
06-03 19:19:48.139: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-internetwarning)=false
06-03 19:19:48.149: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-maxudpport)=65535
06-03 19:19:48.149: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-mimetype)=video/mp4
06-03 19:19:48.149: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-minudpport)=1024
06-03 19:19:48.159: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-romversion)=1.18.707.3
06-03 19:19:48.159: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-rtcpreportinterval)=3000
06-03 19:19:48.159: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-rtptimeout)=25000
06-03 19:19:48.159: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-rtspkeepaliveinterval)=35000
06-03 19:19:48.159: V/HTC_Util(129): skip header(x-htc-rtsptimeout)=25000
06-03 19:19:48.849: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(129): We requested a content range, but server didn't support that. (responded with 200)
06-03 19:19:48.849: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(129): Reconnect failed w/ err 0xffffffe0
06-03 19:19:49.189: D/WifiStateMachine(262): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -51
06-03 19:19:49.829: V/NetworkStatsFactory(262): readNetworkStatsDetail(-1) start
06-03 19:19:49.849: V/NetworkStatsFactory(262): readNetworkStatsDetail(-1) line 48, tooks 21 ms
06-03 19:19:51.859: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(129): Reconnecting...
06-03 19:19:51.859: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(129): ReadFailed happened before
06-03 19:19:51.859: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(129): initiateDisconnect start
06-03 19:19:51.859: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(129): onInitiateDisconnect2 start
06-03 19:19:51.859: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(129): onInitiateDisconnect2 end
06-03 19:19:51.859: I/GCWorkerThread(129): GCNetworkThreadTask::run in
06-03 19:19:51.859: I/GCWorkerThread(129): Delete Context
06-03 19:19:51.869: I/GCWorkerThread(129): GCNetworkThreadTask::run out this = 0x1fe308
06-03 19:19:51.869: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(129): initiateDisconnect end
06-03 19:19:51.869: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(129): af  mDelegate->initiateDisconnect
06-03 19:19:51.869: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(129): disconnect without forcebreak
06-03 19:19:51.869: D/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(129): connect to http://sdf.mysite.com/upload/video/456456.mp4@19601517
06-03 19:20:20.509: E/AwesomePlayer(129): content error
06-03 19:20:20.509: E/MediaPlayer(3936): error (1, -2147483648)
06-03 19:20:20.529: E/MediaPlayer(3936): Error (1,-2147483648)
06-03 19:20:20.529: D/VideoPlayerActivity(3936): onError: arg2=-2147483648 ,mIsDialogShowed: false ,mPhoneCallState:0
06-03 19:20:20.539: D/VideoPlayerActivity(3936): onError: status=3
```

Tried playing the video from the raw folder, but still was unable to do so:

```
06-04 10:03:59.231: D/MediaPlayer(4636): setDataSource(Context context, android.resource://com.asdqwe.asd/2131099649, Map<String, String> headers) in
06-04 10:03:59.231: D/MediaPlayer(4636): [DLNA]unspuuort uri prefix, disable DLNA: android.resource://com.despark.bump/2131099649
06-04 10:03:59.341: D/MediaPlayer(4636): [DLNA]setDisplay
```

Comment: found any solution ? i am facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The MediaPlayer class is actually a frontend for a subsystem within android known as the media player service. It's likely that the devices this is failing on lack vendor support for h264. In my experience with various set top android devices, for example, this system varies in its vendor implementations.

As an aside, chromium for android uses the MediaPlayer class via a series of generated Jni bindings, so if your device does support h264, it should work in chromium. Unfortunately I don't think there's an easy fix, as h264 support isn't guaranteed everywhere. You could try switching to webm, if you have control of the media itself.

Comment: what is a webm? what if I convert videos to .3gp, will that work?

Comment: Webm is a video container format like avi, mpeg, mkv or 3gp to name a few. Don't confuse container with codec; though some container types are suited to specific codecs. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM

Comment: so if we convert videos to webm they will be playable on all phones?

Comment: I don't want to make a guarantee like that, but check out the docs. You should always test your app on as broad of a range of devices as possible. http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

you should try mediacontroller

```
try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                videoscrnplay.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(vdov);

        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        vdov.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        vdov.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```